# UI jquery selectMenu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use UI jquery select menu (jQuery UI - v1.12.1 ) but I need to add search div within it this my code Html please i need 2 question .

1- I want when click selectmenu to show search, which call("sh")div that included in select menu 
 2- how  can  I add (nicescroll jquery.nicescroll 3.2.0) to selectmenu instead of default scroll ?

```
<div action="#" class="search-bar fl-sm">
             <div id="sh" style="height:50px;width:180px;position:absolute; top:40px; z-index:1;background-color:#f00;display:none">    search</div>

        <select name="number" id="city" id="currency-menu" >

            <option selected="selected">Select your City</option>  
        <option >elryad</option>
        <option>cairo</option>
        <option>alex</option>
        <option>tunis</option>
        <option>paris</option>
        <option>ismali</option>
        <option>emrat</option>
        <option>oman</option>
        <option>jda</option>
        <option>england</option>
        <option>london</option>
        <option>france</option>
        <option>knda</option>
        <option>dubi</option>
        <option>mansoura</option>
        <option>unan</option>
        </select>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down arcity" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
        </div>
```

I add this css to show scrol

```
    <style>
        .overflow {
        height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
```

here js

```
  $( "#city" )
            .selectmenu()
            .selectmenu( "menuWidget" )
            .addClass( "overflow" );
$("#city").click(function(){
$("sh").show();
```

})